# How do I create a cocoa binding in interface builder?

Tags: cocoa, macos, cocoa-bindings

Real simple . . . say I create a slider, and I want to bind it to the value of a variable somewhere in my app.  How do I do that?

In particular, I downloaded Apple's [Temperature Converter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleTemperatureConverter/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.  But if I delete one of the bindings, I can't see any way to bring it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the slider in Interface Builder and choose `Tools -> Bindings Inspector`. There, select `Value` and enter the specifics of the binding.

Comment: Adding: Bind views to a controller, not directly to some value. The controller acts as mediator between the model where your values are stored and the views. This is how the Cocoa Bindings top-level stuff is intended to work.